# How to open Document (.doc .ppt .pdf .xlsx) inside Ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I read the document from Ionic Document https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/document-viewer/ but I couldn't find the best method to open Document files like doc, ppt inside the app. Any suggest to solve the issue?

So basically I want to convert every Document file into HTML so the user can open the file through the app. Any suggestion?

This is my TS file :

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DocumentViewer, DocumentViewerOptions } from '@ionic-native/document-viewer';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-e-learning',
  templateUrl: 'e-learning.html',
})
export class ELearningPage {

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public document: DocumentViewer
  ) {

    const options: DocumentViewerOptions = {
      title: 'My PDF'
    }
    this.document.viewDocument('https://s1.q4cdn.com/806093406/files/doc_downloads/test.pdf', 'application/pdf', options)

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ELearning');
  }

}
```

Comment: Where is your document? Is it on your device?

Comment: Please edit the question and be more specific top to bottom, show your code, site where are you stuck.

Comment: @JuniorGantin I'm testing it on my browser, I want to read the Document Files on my ionic apps.

Comment: @MunimMunna I add my code above, can you find me the solution?

Comment: Have you found a solution on this? I am having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried **File Opener**? In Ionic 1 file opener opens a pdf and other file formats.
Check this link for Ionic 3.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-opener/

Comment: The **File Opener** will open default application on your device. I want to convert the file, so the file can be opened inside the ionic apps.

Comment: @pradnya i tried but not working for me i got file not found message in console tell me show to fix?

Comment: @Kapilsoni, which platform are you trying to open a file?

Comment: @PradnyaSinalkar: i used Android platform?

Answer (score 1):

For PDF files, you can use PDF Viewer Component for Angular 5+ [ng2-pdf-viewer](https://github.com/vadimdez/ng2-pdf-viewer/). [Here](https://github.com/plinionaves/ionic3-pdf-viewer) you can find a integration example in Ionic 3.
Hope I help!